# I checked my OAuth Client ID. It exists! But I receive 'The OAuth client was deleted.'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I checked my OAuth Client ID. It does exists! But I receive an error:
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('deleted_client: The OAuth client was deleted.')

[image: screen shot]'

What can I do for resolve it?
This issue rises in a python script:

```
from gspread_pandas import Spread, conf as GPCred
import os

DIR_CRED = '\\gspread_pandas'
dir_script = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
dir_gpandas = dir_script + DIR_CRED
gp_cred = GPCred.get_config(dir_gpandas)    
spread = Spread('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xM_0Seb4_W_FF9Oa8_H8quxovDrRV8Suzxz0-L774Rw')
```

Comment: It is very difficult to answer statements (presumably your question is "How do I resolve this issue?") that include almost no detail. Where do you receive the error? What exactly did you do? Had this ever worked? What may have changed? What did you try?

Comment: Yes. My question is  "What can I do for resolve it?"

Comment: I use module "gspread-pandas" in python and do the same that use to do every time for get to my google spreadsheets but I haven't used my script maybe foe year. And... You can see this error

Comment: The error message normally indicates that the OAuth Client ID or the API Project is already deleted. As a faster solution, you can create a new API Project and then generate new OAuth Client in order to configure your current application. Also, as a kindly recommendation, you can open a [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases) case in order that the team inspect further your project or if you do not have support, open a [PIT](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: Thanks. I'd already done this recommendation. I've created a new project and a new new OAuth Client.  But error still exists :( for this new item

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after deleting a project and creating a new one, creating a new credential and when trying to connect to the google sheet api.

Restoring the old projects didn't solve the problem, but I found that the **client_id** and **client_secret** credentials of the old project are stored and gspread queries them even after creating new project and credentials the program continued using them.

Run this code to find the exact path of the file that stores the old credentials:

```
> def get_config_dir(config_dir_name="gspread", os_is_windows=os.name ==
> "nt"):
>         r"""Construct a config dir path.
>     
>         By default:
>             * `%APPDATA%\gspread` on Windows
>             * `~/.config/gspread` everywhere else
>     
>         """
>         if os_is_windows:
>             return os.path.join(os.environ["APPDATA"], config_dir_name)
>         else:
>             return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".config", config_dir_name)
>     
>     DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR = get_config_dir()
>     
>     DEFAULT_AUTHORIZED_USER_FILENAME = os.path.join(
>         DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR, "authorized_user.json"
>     )
>     
>     print(DEFAULT_AUTHORIZED_USER_FILENAME)
```

Inside this code change the two credentials to the current project.

Notice that when you try to run your code again, it will return that the token is incorrect.

So to adjust the token, cut from this folder (just remove) and run your code to do a new authentication.

Hope this helps.